# App icons don't match the 57 and 114 field icons in MonoTouch!

Tags: iphone, icons, xamarin.ios

I am having some issues assigning the iPhone app icons in MonoTouch -

Initially I only had an 114x114 icon and so assigned it to the iPhone4 field (in the Icon's tab) that expects the 114 image but it didn't come through - neither on the simulator nor the phone itself.  Then when I renamed the icon to icon.png and placed it in the root of the app it comes out ok for some reason...

Now I also created a 57x57 icon and once assigned to the iPhone field in the 'Icons' tab the result is unexpected....

It seems like MonoTouch reverses the icons!!  I have taken the icon.png out of the root folder and the 57x57 is shown on my iPhone4.  However, if I select the 114x114 icon into the 57x57 field and vice versa for my 57x57 icon (place it in the field that expects the 114x114 icon) - you guessed it - it all seems to work! Very strange!!

My crystal sharp icon is displayed on my iPhone4 (even though it is now specified in the 57px field)!  If I then reverse it back to the proper way 'it should be given to MonoTouch' I get a more fuzzy icon on my iPhone4 (ie the 57x57 version).

Has anyone else had difficulties with these icons?  What am I doing wrong?

Any help very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The MonoTouch project property editors are there help manage the icons but you really can't skirt the conventions that iOS expects.  I am not sure exactly what you're doing in your project but it sounds like you aren't following the icon guidelines and conventions.

I'd recommend making sure you're following the guidelines established for icons set out in the iOS developers guide.  Here is a link to the [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) which discusses the sizes, what each size is used for and, most importantly, what the icons should be named.  Do this and I think you'll find that your icon issues will be resolved.