# iPhone App using MonoTouch - which files/folder binaries do I upload to the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have created a small iPhone app using MonoTouch - got all provisioning files etc set up etc and I have done a Distribution build which has created a Distribution folder (under the bin\iPhone folder).

Now in this Distribution folder I can see two more folders called MyGame.app, MyGame.app.dSym and two files MyGame.exe and MyGame.xcent.

Which of these files or folders do I need to zip and upload to the App store??

My guess is it is the MyGame.app folder which is full of files, images, Info.plist, embedded.mobileprovision but it also seems to contain monotouch.dll's and Microsoft's System.Core.dll etc. ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good tutorial in [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net) website

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution

the last lines are

> navigating to the `bin/Distribution/iPhone` directory. Zip the app bundle, and submit it to Apple.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response - I did read it but for some reason my output path is ....game/iPhone/Distribution/MyGame.app so wasn't sure.  Also - being a pure Windows person - I didn't realise the 'bundle' means 'folder'!!

Answer (score 0):

The file with the .app extension is the application bundle.  It's really a "folder" disguised as a file.  You need to zip it up before you can submit it.  Curious, what is the name of your game?  I'm interested in seeing one of these "ported" applications.

Good luck, sir

Comment: I will come back to you with that as soon as I have uploaded it tonight.  I will let you know how it went.

Comment: Oeps - enter submits this directly!

Comment: Damn - again!  - So I take it Apple simply ignores the monotouch.dll and System.dll and System.Core.dll that are also places in that 'bundle' then?

Comment: If you have experience with MonoTouch do you happen to have some thoughts on my second question regarding icons:

Comment: Damn...  again ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105052/app-icons-dont-match-the-57-and-114-field-icons-in-monotouch